# What is Poosball, an early 1900s women's team sport?

Tags: 20th-century, sports

My girlfriend recently showed me a 1908 yearbook in which several women are marked as playing "Poos-ball" or "Poosball." An internet search for this reveals mostly misspellings of "Foosball," however, if the search is specific enough, the most common relevant results lead back to this same high school in Cincinnati.  An [example](http://www.mocavo.com/Hughes-High-School-1913-Cincinnati-Oh/912310/103) and, a photo of the "[A grade Girls' Poos Ball team](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bdtdn.jpg)"!
[image: picture of a sports team lying on the floor looking up to face the camera] The question, of course, is what is Poos Ball? By the ball size, seems like soccer, volleyball, basketball, and water polo are the best bets. All four were invented prior to 1908, though the latter three sports would have been relatively new. However, there is no mention on the internet of any of these being formerly named Poosball! Thoughts?

Comment: First link seems to be broken - Can you check it?

Comment: Link seems to work for me still, but an alternate way of finding it is to google the following: with quotes, google "poosball team", and then under 'showing results for', click 'Search instead for "poosball team"'. All the hits for me are old Hughes HS yearbooks.

Comment: Works for me now also. Maybe the server was offline last night.

Comment: Thank you all for sharing your sources. I first saw reference to Center Ball in my Grandmother's 1916 Hughes High School Annual. I was curious if it was similar to Netball. We appreciate your sharing the rules, we three historians were curious.

Comment: Just for the record, although the capitalization of "Poos Ball" offends me, it is consistent with the sources mentioned - even "Center Ball" and "End Ball" are capitalized in the sources.  I'm jotting down this note to remind me the next time I see this question and try to normalize the capitalization to standard English usage.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Apparently, Poosball was an indoor game similar to basketball. It was also known as center ball and captain ball.

According to [Volume 30 of Mind and Body](http://books.google.gr/books?id=6PmfAAAAMAAJ) (1923) it was invented by Dr. E. A. Poos in 1890 while at the Woodward High School in Cincinnati. Dr Poos wrote a [booklet about the game](http://books.google.gr/books?id=yOictgAACAAJ), but I don't have access to its contents.

The game is also mentioned in:

- [Volume 1 of Rural Manhood](http://books.google.gr/books?id=jBELAAAAIAAJ) (1910)
- The [official handbook of the Cincinnati public schools athletic league](https://archive.org/details/officialhandbook01cinc) (1910)
- The [1918 Hughes High School Annual](https://archive.org/details/hughesannual00hugh_1)
- The [Playground Book: Cincinnati Playgrounds, Under Direction of the Board of Education and the Board of Park Commissioners](http://books.google.gr/books?id=48osAQAAMAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=center%20ball) (1918)

Comment: Dang. Damn shame my grandmother-in-law died last year, or I could have asked her about it. She grew up across the river from Cincinnati, was an athlete, and for a time a High School principal there.

Comment: !THAT! is how to present a well researched answer on an obscure topic.  I can only vote up once.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace well, technically you can assign a bounty ;)

Answer (score -2):

Scroll down to where it begins with CAPTAINBALL in [Mind and Body](https://books.google.com/books?id=6PmfAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA29&lpg=PA29&dq=dr%20e%20a%20poos%20poosball&source=bl&ots=5-ITR_OKnf&sig=ACfU3U2p38AXoCgIbYlhLZf1FNpPQ2Q6OQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi2s8K72cHkAhWkuVkKHd_yA7kQ6AEwDHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false) or the original version of [centerball](https://books.google.com/books?id=48osAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA75&lpg=PA75&dq=centerball%20poos&source=bl&ots=b3DuQubu).

Comment: This would be improved by including the relevant paragraphs in your answer since links can become invalid.

Comment: It's an electronic copy of a book, and I don't seem to have an option to copy/paste from said book.

Comment: You don't seem to be adding anything to the already accepted answer, which already discusses the relationship with **captain ball* and *center ball*.

Answer (score -2):

I'm guessing this is what the game has turned into. I'm not finding any American references to the game any longer. But some [overseas countries seem to like it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rAvqhMGr_hg).  Here are the [rules/How To Play](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UFTP48QiR9o)

Comment: You should edit this into the other answer since its dependent on the content of that.